# Maintaining a set of distinct objects in Java

Tags: java, set, identity, equality

I'm trying to implement a Map in a very memory restricted environment. The value type of the map I expect to have many duplicates (i.e. not just that there are many x and y such that x.equals(y), but many x and y such that x == y). Therefore, I'd like to keep these pointers in a small array (in the common case, less than a few dozen entries), and index into it using an integer which gets inflated out of a byte array; usually this will result in a substantial savings.

This requires though some way of keeping track of the distinct references, though. I could just keep track of them all in some list, and linear-search through it every time a new value is added, but then the map won't scale to more than a few hundred distinct values (and, even though lots of distinct values is uncommon, it's not impossible). This kind of map should be easy for an internal Java class to implement, since it just needs to do pointer comparisons, but this interface doesn't seem to be exposed (in fact, since the default Object hashCode method just returns the underlying pointer in most implementations, I'm in the ironic position of being a Map implementer hurt by users implementing hashCode).

Is there any way to get this sort of behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `java.lang.System.identityHashCode(Object)` and `==` operator?

Comment: Like [IdentityHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you may consider the following:

If you have a map where you have a lot of dublicate values (where `entry1.getValue() == entry2.getValue()` ), then you may use your current values as a key, and the current keys that point to the same object in memory as a list of items.

```
Map<SomeType1, List<SomeType2> map = new IdentityHashMap<SomeType1, List<SIneType2>>();
```